# Typescript throwing an error every time I try to add a new collection type in Strapi

Tags: typescript, strapi

I have a new install of the latest strapi (4.11.1), and am new to the platform.  I'm using Postgres as my backend. Everything was going splendidly until this morning, when trying to add a new collection to my existing definitions. At first I called it "Application", and went through the definition phase, and got an error like this:

```
src/api/application/controllers/application.ts:7:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"api::application.application"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContentType'.

7 export default factories.createCoreController('api::application.application');

src/api/application/routes/application.ts:7:43 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"api::application.application"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ContentType'.

... 

Found 3 error(s).
```

Other related errors were snipped for the sake of brevity.

Thinking that perhaps "Application" was a reserved keyword that I wasn't being warned about, I deleted the "application" folder in src/api, and started over, this time calling it "Package". Same error, new name. So I tried again, but with something that could not possibly be a reserved keyword - "Hutzpah".  Same problem.  I also stopped trying to do a full definition of the collection type, and only added a single text string called "Name". Same problem.  These are the only errors I get.

It seems that for some reason, strapi is not adding the type interface version of the JSON "schema" into `types/generated/contentTypes.d.ts` and this omission is what's causing the errors, but I'm not familiar enough with strapi to understand why this might be the case, or if this is a red herring.

Any help would be most appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran today into the same issue. Same version of strapi and with typescript as well. Did you generate typings as its mentioned here? https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/typescript#generate-typings-for-project-schemas

I figured out it might be the issue, so I removed the generated folder "types" with all its content and now it works fine

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Curiously, I had previously deleted the files that were generated inside the types/generated folder, but did not delete the folder entirely, and the problem persisted.  Deleting the folder altogether per your suggestion DID work, but only until I added another collection again, then the problem repeated itself. Deleted the folder again, it lets me proceed.  So something has gone amok, but this lets me keep going, and also provides good fodder for a bug report, I think.

Comment: I understand. It means that you run command to regenerate them, right? I assume you use it for some kind of automation later on. If you have a similar case as I did, I found this plugin https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-schemas-to-ts that did perform actually better than the original command `strapi ts:generate-types`. At least it didnt cause any errors. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I also run into the same issue 2 days ago. I have followed the guideline provided by Strapi on [TypeScript development](https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/typescript). After investigation, I realized that my `config` folder was empty. I bet yours is empty too. So to fix the issue,

- Just add `config/typescript.js` or `config/typescript.ts` file to your project.
- Then add the following code inside:

```
export default {
   autogenerate: true,
}
```

This will prevent the server from crashing during the restart, hence allow you to save new content-type normally.

Answer (score 3):

because "types" of typescript is not built, so follow the official guideline, or just run :

```
npm run strapi ts:generate-types --debug
```

works well for me.

Comment: this works for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Everything said above is true, but additionally if you are using their docker example with the example docker-compose. Make sure you mount your types directory in your docker-compose file. It's not included in the strapi docs.

```
volumes:
  - ./config:/opt/app/config
  - ./src:/opt/app/src
  - ./types:/opt/app/types # MAKE SURE THIS LINE IS ADDED
  - ./package.json:/opt/package.json
  - ./yarn.lock:/opt/yarn.lock
  - ./.env:/opt/app/.env
  - ./public/uploads:/opt/app/public/uploads
```